# Google cloud run speed varies

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-platform, cloud, fastapi

Thanks for reading my question.

I 've deployed my gcr image to cloud run. The app is based on FastAPI and it has been built on cloud build with dockerfile.

I've set the number of minimum instance as 2 to avoid the cold start and set the CPU as always allocation.

The problem is the cloud run time varies.

The response time is sometimes 2 mins and sometimes 15 mins.

I can't know the reason when on earth it takes 2 mins and when on earth it takes 15 mins.

I am wondering this is the problem of internal system on Google cloud.

Please answer my question.

Comment: There can be multiple answers and not necessarily means the issue is GCP. Instead please share more details like a code snippet or what the app does. Saying it uses FastAPI and Cloud Run is not helpful. Also, what's the time you expect? Have you profiled your app?

Comment: Can you share more detail? Do you have concurrency? Are you requesting external services?

Comment: In my python code , we get the file with size of 1.6 GB  by requesting to the one site and parse this file . We use  xml.etree.iterparse function for parsing this file.

Comment: Can you also share your config in the Cloud run? May I also know if there was no latency problem when running your app locally?